# Change developerConnection with maven release plugin

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-release-plugin

I am using the maven release plugin with git but am running into issues in `release:prepare`.

The developer settings in my pom are as follows:

```
<connection>scm:git:git://git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com:user/repo.git</connection>
<url>scm:git:git://git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com:user/repo.git</url>
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com:user/repo.git</developerConnection>
```

The problem with this is when I run the `release:prepare` goal. It throws the following error

```
https://github.scm.corp.mycompany.com:user/repo.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

and release fails. It is able to do the git commit, git status succesfully. Error happens in git push

In the scm when i change the last `:` to a `/` it works perfectly. So the following SCM works:

```
<connection>scm:git:git://git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git</connection>
<url>scm:git:git://git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git</url>
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git</developerConnection>
```

There a lot of other external projects in the org repo that are to be released. So it is not possible to change this in every projects pom all the time.

Any pointers on why the former scm tag values with the `:` do not work but the ones with the `/` work?

Is there a way to override this scm information by specifying it as a part of release goals?

I am specifying these options with my maven goals but it does not override

```
-Dproject.scm.connection="scm:git:git@github.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git"
-Dproject.scm.url="scm:git:git@github.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git"
-Dproject.scm.developerConnection="scm:git:git@github.corp.mycompany.com/user/repo.git"
```

**EDIT:**

Maven Release Plugin version is 2.2.1 and Maven Version is 3.0.5

Comment: Change the appropriate pom's and fix the problem. Otherwise you need to always give all that stuff on command line which is really hard.

Comment: @khmarbaise Specifying it in the command line everytime is not an issue as it can be automated with a Jenkins Job. I need to know a way to override the developer connection settings specified in my pom when I specify the maven goals.

Comment: First yes you can but should change the pom's. Furthermore why are you using such an old version of the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The plugin version is that which is inherited from the parent POM of the project. So we do not have control on it. If there is a way could you suggest me how to do it? i tried the -Dproject.scm.developerConnection option but that does not seem to work!